# Como tirar a linha horizontal da table no bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap, table

Mesmo lendo vários artigos na net sobre table

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/ 
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tables.asp

não consegui tirar uma dúvida.
**Como tirar a linha horizontal da table no bootstrap** 
Abaixo deixo uma imagem como exemplo de uma table simples onde
existem 3 linhas em cinza bem clarinho que separam os registros.
Como remove-las?? Tentei usar o border, mas o mesmo só funciona para a borada :)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de ter o resultado como na imagem abaixo (editei a primeira imagem )
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

Uma *alternativa* para remover as bordas seria assim:

```
table td{
  border:none !important;
}
```

*Nota que é preciso usar o `!important` para ignorar o estilo atribuído pelo próprio bootstrap, **cuidado** que esse trecho css irá remover toda e qualquer borda de todas as `td's`, caso queira remover somente de uma table específica, referencie ela através de uma classe ou um id.

Segue um fiddle com um exemplo: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mathiasfcx/dqq5B/664/)

Comment: Boa tarde Mathias.. Entendi o que você respondeu.. Sou novo no bootstrap então vai uma outra pergunta.. Teria como eu fazer um objeto TABLE01 herdando de table e ai então colocar o código que você demonstrou na TABLE01?? Como eu faria esse lance de herança no bootstrap/css ?? Outro arquivo??  Dentro do arquivo Bootstrap.css??? Obrigado pela atenção :)

Comment: @RicardoM.Souza da uma olhada no fiddle novamente, atualizei de maneira que a remoção de borda  seja feita somente na table com `id="TABLE01"`

Comment: Boa tarde... novamente... :) Muito legal o lance do ID :). Obrigado pela sua atenção e Abraços :)

Comment: Na verdade o `!important` não é necessário já que você já está manipulando a tabela pelo id.

Comment: @ViniciusKiss realmente, é que no exemplo anterior eu estava trabalhando com o seletor `table td{...}`, depois de atualizado o exemplo, o `!important` não é mais necessário.